# sklearn SVM RBF overfitting sin wave

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I am using an SVM to learn a sin wave from noisy input. I have tried many different hyper-parameters, but the model still seems to overfitting quite severely. I am not sure if I am just asking the model to do more than it can, or if I simply chose the wrong hyper-parameters. Perhaps there is a better model I can use for this task? I can show graphs of the input and output if that helps. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def svr(x, y, C=1, gamma=.1):
    # train/test split
    split = int(y.shape[0] * 0.8)
    x_train, x_test = x[:split], x[split:]
    y_train, y_test = y[:split], y[split:]

    # fit SVM
    svrm = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=C, gamma=gamma)  
    svr_fit = svrm.fit(x_train, y_train.flatten())

    # make predictions on train and test sets
    y_fitted = svr_fit.predict(x_train)
    y_predicted = svr_fit.predict(x_test)
    print('Done!')

    return y_fitted, y_predicted

lin = np.linspace(0, 100, 5000)
rand = np.random.random(lin.shape)
sin = np.sin(lin)

x = (sin + rand/2 - 0.25).reshape((-1, 1))
y = sin.reshape((-1, 1))
print(x.shape, y.shape)

plt.plot(lin, sin)
plt.show()
plt.plot(lin[:500], x.flatten()[:500])
plt.show()

y_fit, y_pred = svr(x, y, C=1, gamma=.1)

plt.plot(lin[:len(y_fit)], y_fit)
plt.show()
plt.plot(lin[len(y_fit):], y_pred)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The default `epsilon` is `0.1` - isn't that too big for your case?

Comment: I have tried with values as low as 1e-6, not much difference in terms of performance.

Comment: Posting the plots would be helpful yes, but you might also want to try https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89984/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49542914/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @BartoszKP, may I make a request for the future?  In the future, if you're going to suggest another site, can you please let the poster know that they should not post on more than one site?  You can suggest that they delete the question here before posting it elsewhere.  In case you were unaware, posting on multiple sites is not allowed by Stack Exchange rules -- see the link in my previous comment.  Hopefully this will provide a better experience both for posters and for answerers.  Thanks for listening!

Comment: @D.W. Sure, I'll try to remember about that, thanks :)